# preg_match returns false

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a web page in PHP that will provide some useful tools and information related to a [Minecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft) server.

I am working on a "status indicator", a system to detect if something is wrong with the server. One of the parts of this system is to use *shell_exec* to check if there is a server application running on the system. I am using [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to check if the result of *shell_exec* indicates that there is a server application running.

The problem is that no matter what I do, preg_match seems to always return false, which indicates that an error has occurred. I can't find any details about what exactly this error could be.

```
function get_server_app_status($appName)
{
    if (preg_match($appName, shell_exec('ps aux | grep ' . $appName . ' | grep -v grep')) != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have verified that *shell_exec* returns what I want it to by shoving it into a variable and checking its value with a debugger, as well as checking $appName. Both are strings and have the values I want them to.

I have also checked what preg_match returns the same way and it does return false, not just zero.

Comment: just to confirm, this will only return true if the string you're trying to match is at the start of the input string

Comment: can you provide us some of your code ?

Comment: You can probably find a more concise way to write `if (boolean_expression) { return true; } else { return false; }`...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you need to give an actual pattern to preg_match, which $appname may or may not be (intuitively, usually it won't be a pattern, based on the code).

Comment: This is a useful site (page) for testing preg_* things: http://www.fullonrobotchubby.co.uk/random/preg_tester/preg_tester.php

Comment: To expand on @MarkByers' comment, you could rewrite that as simply `return (bool) preg_match( ... );`

Comment: @DaveRandom - Woooosh ;)

Comment: What kind of system is implied? [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) with [Raspbian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) ([Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian)/[Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) derivative)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tested the return value for NULL.
And this worked perfectly

```
function get_server_app_status($appName)
{
    $result = shell_exec('ps aux | grep ' . $appName . ' | grep -v grep');
    if (!is_null($result)) {
        // app is running
    } else {
        // app is NOT running
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't shell_exec return at least a newline character? But I'll try this too.

Answer (score 6):

In your code snippet:

```
 if (preg_match($appName, shell_exec(...
```

is `$appName` a valid regex?

You probably meant something like:

```
if (preg_match("/" . preg_quote($appName) . "/", shell_exec(...
```

But if `$appName` is just a string, then you'll be better off just using a string comparison function than a regex, like `strcmp` or `strpos` or even `==`.

Comment: +1 this - note that while `grep` does use a limited form of regex for it's filter (POSIX regex), it does not use the same form of PCRE regex used by PHP's `preg_*` functions. At the very minimum it will need to be encapsulated in delimiters (like `/`) as suggested in this answer, and it may need other transformations as well. You may get some joy from using `ereg()` instead, although this is deprecated and **NOT** a recommended approach. If all you need to do is look for a specific, static string in the output then `strpos()` is definitely a better option.

Comment: I have to include anything besides the string to match to get a valid regex? Huh, and I thought it worked just like Unix grep...

Answer (score 2):

If `$appName` is a string and not a regular expression, just use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
function get_server_app_status($appName) {
    return strpos($appName, shell_exec('ps aux | grep ' . $appName . ' | grep -v grep')) !== false;
}
```

Comment: Also, values of the two variables: $appName is set to craftbukkit.jar and $shExecResult is set to 9422  4.3 12.7 1250348 259152 pts/2  Sl+  00:35  36:24 java -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui\n

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative that uses "pgrep" if available on your server environment.

```
<?php
function get_server_app_status($appName) {
  return shell_exec("pgrep $appName");
}

// Test driver
echo sprintf("Running: %s" . PHP_EOL, (get_server_app_status('httpd')) ? 'Yes' : 'No');
echo sprintf("Running: %s" . PHP_EOL, (get_server_app_status('java')) ? 'Yes' : 'No');
```

Here is the output testing for httpd and a nonexistent case.

```
./5 proc.php
```

Output:

```
Running: Yes
Running: No
```

Note: *./5* is a symlink to my PHP binary.

Comment: The problem is that the server app is named java and I have more than one server app running, one bukkit and one vanilla (which therefore have different file names). If I want to add another I can just use a different file name.

Comment: Oh. The last two lines are just my test cases. Substitute with any program you are expecting to find.